# reinterpret_cast< > from one structure to another

Tags: c++, casting

I'm going through a win32 program and I found part of a code contained `reinterpret_cast<>` from one structure to another. What happens to

```
PKT_HEADER* pPktHeader = reinterpret_cast<PKT_HEADER*>( buffer );
```

`pPktHeader` and `buffer` are two structure pointers.

My question is what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

To be pedantic, it's casting one pointer to another, not one structure to another.  In most environments, pointers to objects are the same size, whatever the object - so this can work.

It is telling the compiler to assume that the buffer actually holds a `PKT_HEADER`.  If it does, then it should work fine.  If the `buffer` contains a different data structure, then using `pPktHeader` would be undefined behavior, and anything could happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big misunderstanding on your side. It is `reinterpret_cast` of pointer to one structure, to pointer to another structure. The effect is the same as C-style casts. The block of memory pointed by `buffer` is going to be reinterpreted as `PKT_HEADER` structure.